# icefaces multiple window support for same session

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

i have application which made with ice:faces ..
i want to make support of multiple window with same session
is it possible in ice:faces ?
in web.xml
i have put the tag like that

```
<context-param>
<param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I am able to open multiple window but problem is I can't make changes from both window concurrently.

Comment: What problem occurs when you try to do that? If getting error, post the log details.

Comment: If multiple window open and i refresh page then i am logout from current one.

Comment: If i write like <param-value>false</param-value> then last window update reflected on other one.

Answer (score 0):

From ICEfaces Documentation :

> With concurrent DOM views enabled,
>   each browser window is distinctly
>   identified with a view number and DOM
>   updates will be correctly applied to
>   the appropriate window. This
>   introduces some important
>   considerations for the application
>   data model. Managed beans in session
>   scope can now be shared across
>   multiple views simultaneously. This
>   may be the desired scope for some
>   states, but typically,
>   presentation-related state is more
>   appropriately kept in request scope.
>
> Request scope : For typical
>   view-related state, request-scope
>   beans will persist through most user
>   interaction but not through view
>   changes. This is the recommended scope
>   for ICEfaces applications that make
>   use of multiple windows.
>
> Session scope : For state that must be
>   shared across views.

When you set parameter as `true` supports multiple views, but have to use request scoped beans. Probably forcing logout from current session if another window is opened.

> If concurrent DOM views is configured,
>   and multiple windows are created by
>   the user, ICEfaces uses a single
>   blocking connection to deliver
>   asynchronous updates to all views in
>   the session.

And when set as `false` supporting single view, the changes in a window gets reflected in another.

Comment: i tried with session scope and DOM true also but still it gives same result.And change all request scope to session is not a feasible solution :) .

Comment: @chetan I think you have misunderstood & tested the scenario with session scope instead of request scoped beans. And for feasibility, these things need to be considered at project initiation time.

Comment: If i am not wrong you want to say that change request scope from session to loginBean as i am using loginBean as backingBean used at login time. Is it correct interpretation ?

Comment: and sorry for that misunderstanding

Comment: Its fine, but it should work properly with request scoped beans, there might be some problem in your configuration. Instead of implementing in your project directly, try creating a sample project to sort out the things clearly.

Comment: i also tested on sample application the only difference i found between session and request scope is i can't use this line LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean)context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("loginBean"); by using request scope. otherwise almost same behavior found for both

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out the problem you are facing, I haven't tried yet, but according to the official documentation should work.